# Disable use of or catch when user presses Alt + F4 in MS Access App

Tags: ms-access

I like to run some code when a user closes my ms 2000 app. This is being bypassed by the user pressing alt F4 and not using the exit buttons provided, how do i disable this functionality? Alternatively, is there a way to catch this and run some code. Im trying to avoid using a hidden form by the way.

Comment: Why are you trynig to avoid using a hidden form when that's the standard solution to the problem?

Comment: I was trying to avoid extra resource usage in my app. I am going to use a hidden form now though, there is something else that i can implement using it which hasnt got a better alternative method either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use an autokeys macro.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159349%28office.10%29.aspx

EDIT re Conmments

It may suit to create a hidden start-up form or to use your main menu to cancel the close event unless your button is pressed:

> 1. Set the CloseButton propert of the form to No.  You can alternately set
>      the ControlBox property to No, which
>      removes both the 'x' and the min max
>      buttons.
> 2. In the declaration's area of the form's VBA code, define the following
>      variable:
>
>    Public OK2Close As Boolean
> 3. In the form's OnLoad event, place the following code:
>
>    OK2Close = False
> 4. On your form should be a button to close the form (or Quit the
>      application if on the Main screen). 
>      In the OnClick event for this button,
>      place:
>
>    OK2Close = True
>      DoCmd.Close     '(or DoCmd.Quit for Main screen)
> 5. In the form's Unload event, place:
>
>    Cancel = Not OK2Close

From: http://tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1870

Comment: in practice the autokeys function can't be used to capture ALT keystrokes, the article is wrong unfortunately according to http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/Access_Coding-Macros/Q_22497478.html

Comment: using the Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer) checking where Shift = 4 And KeyCode = vbKeyF4 in every form seems a possible route, but this is messy

Comment: I can't test this at the moment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245746 but it may be of interest.